# Cannot add Remote Service from a local GeoServer to Geonode

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I am new to Geonode and I know this is a very basic question.

I am struggling a lot with adding a remote service in `Geonode` using a `WMS` from `GeoServer`.

Why do I get back this error?

```
Could not connect to the service at http://localhost:8888/geoserver/test/wms
```

[image]

I cannot get **why** this happens and **how** it can be solved.

If I open the link on the browser:
[image]

Comment: can you open the link directly?

Comment: If I use this URL for creating a URL connection in QGIS it works.

Comment: I am going to add what I get if I open the link on the browser on the question: It is too long to be added here.

Comment: Please remember to always include error messages as text within your Question body. Images are not legible on all platforms and are not free-text searchable.

Comment: The link should not work in a browser. It's just a base URL for the desired operation. Have you tried removing the questionmark?

Comment: @Stefan, Yes, I have, but still got the same error

Comment: I have never used Geonode myself, but probably there is a logfile. It might provide more details on the error. If not, you can use wireshark (or similar) to capture the network traffic and see how Geonode's actual request looks like and what kind of response Geoserver returns.